# Raster Calculator with multiple rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have 2 rasters in ArcGIS Pro

Raster 1: Values of 0-100 for percentage of tree cover

Raster 2: Values of 0-19 for tree cover loss by year (0 is no loss, 1 is loss in 2001, etc.)

I am trying to find the values of raster 1 where raster 2 values = 1, 2, etc.

How can I do this?

My initial thought was:

```
Con("Raster2" == 1, "Raster1", 0)
```

but this did not give me what I wanted